# CSS navigation bar indication trouble

Tags: html, css

PS:
If you look closely at the bar when your hovering over a link a few pixels at the far right side stay black. Why is that and how do I fix it?

The code for the current Navigation bar is as follows:

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="home.html" id="current">-home</a>
        <a href="about.html">about</a>
        <a href="store.html">store</a>
        <a href="contact.html">contact</a>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar{
width: 75%;
background-color: black;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
margin-top: 15px;}
.navbar a:link, a:visited{
background-color: black;
color: white;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
border-right: 2px solid white;
font-weight: bold;
font-family: verdana;
font-size: 37px;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;}
.navbar a:hover, a:active, a:focus{
background-color: #4A4A4A;
text-decoration: underline;}
#current a:link, a:visited{
background-color: red;}
```

As you can tell by the code, I'm trying to set the color of the home link to red. But this obviously didn't work. How should I go about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

current is the id of the link element, so `#current {background-color:red;}` should do.

Now you're trying to set the color of the link element inside the element with id current.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS rule from :

```
#current a:link, a:visited{
background-color: red;}
```

to

```
#current {
background-color: red;}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7RRMT/)**

Your rule specifies the element with an ID of #current and then the child links of it when just #current is enough.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot comma after #current in your CSS. You don't need rest of line. Also you can write either `#current` only or `a#current`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is incorrect.

```
#current a:link
```

this is saying style a link INSIDE an element with an Id #current

however your link IS the element with the id, try this:

```
a#current { color: red; }
```

It would better better to use a class though:

```
a.red { color: red; }
```

and then:

```
<a class="red">bla</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The main issue, as everyone has indicated is that the element that you are trying to change #current is also the anchor tag, so you have to say a#current:link or #current instead of #current a:link since the anchor tag is not a child of the #current tag.

Here's [my jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jennyfofenny/td3SB/), if you're interested.